# Different behavior between MySQL 5.5 and 5.6

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, group-by

I have this schema with data:

```
CREATE TABLE `ticket` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `type` INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `task` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticket_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_task_1_idx` (`ticket_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_task_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ticket_id`) REFERENCES `ticket` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `planing` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `task_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_planing_1_idx` (`task_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_planing_1` FOREIGN KEY (`task_id`) REFERENCES `task` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;

INSERT INTO `ticket` (`id`, `name`, `type`) VALUES (1, 'ticket_1', 1);
INSERT INTO `task` (`id`, `name`, `ticket_id`) VALUES (1, 'task_1', 1);
INSERT INTO `task` (`id`, `name`, `ticket_id`) VALUES (2, 'task_2', 1);
INSERT INTO `planing` (`id`, `date`, `task_id`) VALUES (1, '2016-06-01 05:00', 2);

INSERT INTO `ticket` (`id`, `name`, `type`) VALUES (2, 'ticket_2', 1);
INSERT INTO `task` (`id`, `name`, `ticket_id`) VALUES (3, 'task_3', 2);
INSERT INTO `task` (`id`, `name`, `ticket_id`) VALUES (4, 'task_4', 2);
INSERT INTO `planing` (`id`, `date`, `task_id`) VALUES (2, '2016-06-01 05:00', 3);
INSERT INTO `planing` (`id`, `date`, `task_id`) VALUES (3, '2016-07-01 05:00', 4);

INSERT INTO `ticket` (`id`, `name`, `type`) VALUES (3, 'ticket_3', 1);
```

When I perform a select:

```
SELECT ticket.id AS ticket_id, task.id AS task_id, planing.date as due_date 
FROM ticket
  LEFT JOIN task ON task.ticket_id = ticket.id
  LEFT JOIN planing ON (task.id = planing.task_id AND planing.date IS NOT NULL)
WHERE ticket.type = 1
GROUP BY ticket.id
ORDER BY planing.date ASC
;
```

on MySQL 5.5 I get

```
ticket_id | task_id | due_date
1         |1        |null   
3         |null     |null   
2         |3        |2016-06-01 05:00:00
```

and on MySQL 5.6 I get

```
ticket_id | task_id | due_date
3         |null     |null   
1         |2        |2016-06-01 05:00:00    
2         |3        |2016-06-01 05:00:00
```

[example link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd37d0/1/0)

How to get the same behavior on MySQL 5.5 as on MySQL 5.6 (app server uses the MySQL 5.5 version)?

Comment: Please tell me that those aren't actual field names. Calling everything `id` is a recipe for confusion when debugging - maybe table_name_id? Also, `date` (an SQL keyword) and `type` (also used in pgsql) - not a great idea. Just because it's possible, doesn't mean that you should do it. You should consider PostgreSQL if you want consistency in your queries.

Comment: Can you improve the question title please? It's very vague atm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to stop relying on the non-standard behaviour provided by GROUP BY when the `only_full_group_by` SQL mode is not enabled.

Normally, when grouping, you cannot retrieve a column that is not specified in the GROUP BY clause unless you wrap it in an aggregate function. That is because that column may have many different values (remember, we are talking about *grouped* rows) and there is no way to specify which value of the many should be used in the output. There is a recent extension to that behaviour according to which columns that are functionally dependent on the GROUP BY columns may be selected without specifying them in the GROUP BY, but MySQL has so far went the simple road of offering you just two modes: either you cannot retrieve non-GROUP BY columns without aggregation at all or you can retrieve *any* such columns, regardless of functional dependence.

So, in this case, you are retrieving columns `task_id` and `due_date` that clearly can have various values per `ticket_id`. Which value is ultimately selected is **out of your control, and that is the problem**. The solution is to define for yourself exactly which row from the other tables you want to get when you are grouping by `ticket.id` and implement the logic the way it can be followed unambiguously.

For instance, if you want to go by the behaviour you are observing in MySQL 5.6, you could define it as

> the earliest non-NULL `due_date` and its corresponding `task_id` per `ticket_id`.

Based on that, you could define the logic [as follows](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd37d/6):

```
SELECT
  ticket.id AS ticket_id,
  (
    SELECT
      MIN(p2.task_id)
    FROM
      task AS t2
      INNER JOIN planing AS p2 ON t2.id = p2.task_id
    WHERE
      p2.date = MIN(planing.date)
      AND t2.ticket_id = ticket.id
  ) AS task_id,
  MIN(planing.date) AS due_date
FROM
  ticket 
  LEFT JOIN task ON task.ticket_id = ticket.id
  LEFT JOIN planing ON task.id = planing.task_id
WHERE
  ticket.type = 1
GROUP BY
  ticket.id
ORDER BY
  MIN(planing.date) ASC
;
```

This is certainly much more coding than your original query, but the extra bit of code is not redundant, because this way you are making your results **predictable**.

The only simpler alternative that **might** emulate the MySQL 5.6 behaviour could be to rewrite the query [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd37d/2):

```
SELECT
  ticket.id AS ticket_id,
  task_id AS task_id,
  planing.date as due_date
FROM
  ticket 
  LEFT JOIN
    task
    INNER JOIN planing ON task.id = planing.task_id
  ON task.ticket_id = ticket.id
WHERE
  ticket.type = 1
GROUP BY
  ticket.id
ORDER BY
  MIN(planing.date) ASC
;
```

In my tests, the above query returned the same results for 5.5 as the original did for 5.6 for your example. Although the two queries should logically give equivalent results, they are not *exactly* equivalent: the rewritten query explicitly changes the logical order of joins. Perhaps that prompted MySQL to choose a different path through the data.

But whatever the reason for the different output, please keep in mind that there is **no guarantee** the behaviour will match **for every scenario**. I will repeat, you need to stop relying on the behaviour that is not documented, or, actually, [**documented to be undefined**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html):

> The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I decided to run the schema through PostgreSQL. Interestingly Andriy, your queries both fail on PostgreSQL. My understanding was that the point of your queries was to have a "standard" query. PostgreSQL is very much standards oriented so it seems to me that a standard query should work with PostgreSQL?

Comment: @Vérace: The second one is just a minor tweak that happened to cause MySQL 5.5 to return the same output as 5.6, it still uses non-standard GROUP BY. The first one was supposed to be a standard SQL replacement. My mistake is the `task.ticket_id` reference in the subquery. It should be `ticket.id` instead. Thanks for pointing this out, I'm editing my question.

Answer (score 3):

Short version: You can't. At least not with that query.

You are relying an extension To MySQL that permits you to SELECT columns that are not aggregated columns, nor listed in the GROUP BY clause.

Specifically, for `ticket_id=1`, you have 2 rows returned, prior to grouping them. One has `task_id=1` and the other `task_id=2`.

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html):

> The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they
>   are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the
>   selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an
>   ORDER BY clause.

That is what you are seeing. The fact that you went from 5.5 to 5.6 is not relevant, as the server can potentially return either result on either version, and explicitly states in the documentation that it will do so.

You can try this query:

```
SELECT ticket.id AS ticket_id, task_planing.task_id AS task_id, task_planing.date as due_date 
FROM ticket
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT
  task.ticket_id,
  task.id AS task_id,
  planing.date
  FROM task
  INNER JOIN planing
  ON task.id = planing.task_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN planing later_planing
  ON later_planing.task_id = planing.task_id
  AND later_planing.date > planing.date
  WHERE later_planing.task_id IS NULL
) AS task_planing
ON task_planing.ticket_id = ticket.id
WHERE ticket.type = 1
GROUP BY ticket.id
ORDER BY task_planing.date ASC
;
```

It makes an assumption that the columns in the `planing` table are not actually NULL, as they are not in your sample data. If some data is actually null, then you will need something different, as your choice to allow NULLs complicates queries like this.

Comment: This query won't work under PostgreSQL either.